# SDL automatically closes window in MinGW when using IMG_Load

Tags: c++, mingw, sdl

So I have been following [this set of tutorials](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.php) to get myself some general knowledge with SDL before going to make a game engine with it.  However, once I reached [this part of the tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/06_extension_libraries_and_loading_other_image_formats/index.php), I started having issues.

Whenever I would try to use IMG_Load or any related commands, it would cause the program to instantly close. I was doing just fine when I was using SDL_LoadBMP, but now the problem only started to arise now. Even when I copy the code in the tutorial exactly, it still wants to be disagreeable.

```
bool init()
{
    //Initialization flags
    bool success = true;

    //Initiralize SDL
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        printf("SDL failed to initialize! Details: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        //Set texture filtering to linear
        if( !SDL_SetHint( SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "1" ) )
        {
            printf( "Warning: Linear texture filtering not enabled!" );
        }

        //Create a window
        gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("densipoint", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if(gWindow == 0)
        {
            printf("Window failed to display! Details: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
            success = false;
        }

        else
        {
            //Create renderer for window
            gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
            if(gRenderer == 0)
            {
                printf("Renderer failed to be created! Details: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
                success = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //Initialize renderer color
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff);

                //Initialize PNG loading
                int imgFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
                if( !( IMG_Init( imgFlags ) & imgFlags ))
                {
                    printf("SDL_image failed to initialize! Details: %s\n", IMG_GetError());
                    success = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

Any ideas/advice? I'm using command-line MinGW with the g++ compiler.

EDIT: I have narrowed the problem down to issues with initializing SDL_image.

```
        int imgFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
        if( !( IMG_Init( imgFlags ) & imgFlags ))
        {
            printf("SDL_image failed to initialize! Details: %s\n", IMG_GetError());
            success = false;
        }
```

Comment: Instead of writing that it "automatically closes the window" and "wants to be disagreeable", could you try running it through a debugger, like `gdb`, and get a more precise description of the problem?

Comment: Also, could you try it with a less scary file name, like `bob.png`?

Comment: Oh, the memory leaks!

Comment: @ChrisBeck Using this, I was able to narrow the problem down to this specific area.
    `int imgFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
    if( !( IMG_Init( imgFlags ) & imgFlags ) )`
It fails to initialize IMG loading, and then proceeds to shut down. Any issues there?

Comment: Are you linking to SDL2_image properly? That's the most likely cause

Comment: It's hard to link it incorrectly, but initialization failure also may caused by missing .dll's. You need to put .dll files which come with SDL_Img in a same directory with your .exe.